# Postman post request stuck on sending

Tags: javascript, express, request, postman, backend

(Express) Hello I'm trying to make a very simple post request to localhost via postman but it gets stuck on sending. To be clear, the first time I've tried it, it worked, but after adding a mongoose implementation it didn't work anymore even after commenting the changes.

```
const router = require('express').Router();

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Got here");
    res.send("ciao");
});
 
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port: " + port);
});
```

[If it was working correctly I'd see "Got here"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Msxzr.png)

[Postman app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkFqG.png)

I'm using postman 8.0.2 desktop app for mac, i've tried to remove and install again.

EDIT
I've tried creating another project and it works again i'll investigate on what i did wrong and maybe add a comment.

Comment: @Adam nope, mongo connection is commented, even if it didn't it was ok no problems with that

Comment: Try this:app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add router as middleware to the express,
below is your updated code

```
const router = require('express').Router();

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Got here");
    res.send("ciao");
});

app.use('/', router);
 
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port: " + port)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, i've tried it doesn't help

Comment: @FedericoTarascio this is working on my system, "Got here" is getting printed, can you restart your app and run it again

Comment: Yes i've tried it on another project and it works again don't know what i did wrong on the first one

Comment: @FedericoTarascio I saw you were using nodemon, I think nodemon is maybe culprit here, things similar to this has  happened to me several times because of nodemon.